# tSSH-Talend blockes job from continuing Run

Tags: docker, ssh, parallel-processing, talend

I use a tSSH Component to call a docker-image which is on a remote Server. 
This docker image will create a Json File which will indicate the end of the process. 
However in my job, I have also a parallel process to check the availability of the file to be copied to the local Talend machine with SCP. 
It is simple, I wrote a script on the same machine as the docker-image, this script will check if the file is available and it will write something like that when I call it with Talend :

Like I mentioned, note that this test is running in parallel to the main script.

[image]

My joblet (it is a joblet because I have many scripts to run this way) :

[image]

[image]

as you can see, a tParallelize is there to run both processes at the same time.

As I said, I have many scripts to run this way with the same logic each time and it works fine unless the main script does not take too long to execute.

The tSSh freezes and blocks the whole java job. Bottom part of parallelize responds and will copy the json file to the local machine but not the upper part.

[image]

No timeout is configured, and both "errors" and "stdout" are redirected to a FullLogFile by triggering the OnComponentOK link.

If it can help, the main script(which causes the problem) execution can last 100hours in worst cases and a few (7,8, or 9) hours in best cases. Other scripts take only few minutes to execute, this is why I never had a problem executing them.

The server logs can reach 3Mo  (but this time the log size on server is only 0,7Mo and it blockes) assuming that the freeze comes out from the redirection of "errors" and "stdout" ? who knows ?

Searching on the internet I did found that I am not the only person who faces this trouble :

https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/tssh-timeout-process-blocked/td-p/60402

[https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/tSSH-component-is-not-ending-and-keeps-on-running-when-executing/td-p/196518](http://%20https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/tSSH-component-is-not-ending-and-keeps-on-running-when-executing/td-p/196518)

Any help or same experience share will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding an exit command, as given in your first link ?

Answer (score 0):

Same answer from another thread.

It is possible that the problem is related to the keepalive on the ssh server side.

Does the connection go through firewalls or vpn?

You can try to connect with a simple ssh client, and if after an hour you are disconnected having typed nothing at the client, it is because a network equipment closes the connection.

more info here :)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200239/how-can-i-keep-my-ssh-sessions-from-freezing